# laravel livewire display flash message, hide it in 3 seconds. show again when it is fired again

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am trying to show the session messages in laravel livewire. The following code works for me. It shows the session message and hides it in 3 seconds. However, the problem is if I submit the same form again, the message won't show as it is already `style="display:none"`

```
@if ($message = Session::get('action_message'))
    <div x-data="{ show: true }" x-show="show" x-init="setTimeout(() => show = false, 3000)">
    
    <div class="mx-2 p-2 bg-{{$message[1]}}-500 text-white rounded-md flex justify-between">
        
        <p>{{$message[0]}}</p>
    
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

controller code for firing the message

```
session()->flash('action_message',[$message.$this->sku,'green']);
```

I am looking to have a message display system which displays message when fired from controller, hides in 3 seconds, and show again when controller fires it again.

Comment: You may need to use AlpineJS for displaying flash messages on your page. Here is a sample example: https://codepen.io/hugodf/pen/dyojOoO